# plot a 1 x n vector in a two dimensional cartesian coordinate system

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I have a 1 x 10 vector as shown below:

```
V = [0.500 -5.433 0.543 0.321 1.432 0.543 -0.576 -0.145 -1.322 -0.222]
```

and want to plot this on MATLAB using `plot`.

I used `plot(v,0,'kx,'marker',10)` but it does not seem reasonable for me. Any idea on how to go about with this?

---

Does anyone have a very good resource for for ISOMAP? Need a very comprehensive step by step easy tutorials on Isomaps. If i can have good videos on it will be very good.

Answer (score 1):

you almost got it, just write:

```
plot(v,'kx','MarkerSize',10);
```

note, that I wrote `plot` and not `Plot`, Matlab is case sensitive...
when you only have a single vector the plot function assumes that for the x-axis it takes the number of elements of the vector, i.e. `plot(1:numel(v),v,...)`. I recommend you to use the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), if you had read it, you'd see an example that could show you what you did wrong.

Comment: I am aware of the case sensitivity in matlab. I just mistakenly type upper case for p when i was posting this problem, but i use lower case in my program.
I have used plot(v,'kx','MarkerSize',10); you suggested, but it is still not putting them in a straight line. I thought all the points should lay on a straight line since it is a 1D vector.

Comment: what did you expect? the values of `v` vs the num of element of `v` (1 to 10) shouldn't show a straight line... Did you read the documentation?

Comment: So plot(v,'kx','MarkerSize',10); is correct for for plotting the a 1D vector?

Comment: Let's see if this time it'll work: **Did you even try read the documentation?**

Comment: I read the documents and i have followed it. It is not giving me straight line. You can test plot(v,'kx','MarkerSize',10) with this vector and see what you will have. It won't be a straight line.
V = [0.500 -5.433 0.543 0.321 1.432 0.543 -0.576 -0.145 -1.322 -0.222]

Comment: a straight line is a line that follows the line eq, `y=a*x+b`. Here you have only one vector `v` and using `plot(v)`, you actually plot `v` values vs 1:10 (the num of values in v), or `plot(1:10,v)`. In order for `v` to be a straight line its values need to depend linearly in some other vector. The values of `v` are `0.500 -5.433 0.543` not exactly a linear growth, but lets say it is just because `v` isn't sorted. If you had another vector (call it `y`) that can be described as `y=a*v+b`, where `a` and `b` are some numbers, then `plot(y,v)` will yield a straight line.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you saying. I will just use it and due to the unsorted nature of the points , it won't be a straight line as i expect. 
Now if some wants to calculate the probability of two independent random variable,say P(x,y), i know it will be p(x,y) = p(x)*p(y).
How can i calculate p(x) and p(y) in matlab given both x and y have mean say 0 and variance of 2 and 4 respectively. How can i go about doping this?
thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have a full step by step derivation of Classical multidimensional Scaling? videos of it is also welcome

Answer (score 0):

`bla`'s solution is okay and produces a scatter plot.

However, you can make a line plot, etc.

Though, notice it is `V` and not `v`, as he pointed out that MATLAB is case-sensitive.

**Here is how to generate a line plot:**

```
x=0:length(V)
plot(x,V,'r--o',x,V,'r*')
```

**Output:**

[image]